# internal assert failed reference.ts has not been loaded

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, reference

I get error message when I am loading my app with IE10.

I am building an app with Angular 4 and firebase 4.3.0.

I have tested the app with Chrome, Firefox, IE11 and it's working fine.

But when I run it on IE10 on Window 7 and emulate IE10 in Windows 10, it produces error like below.

I have included necessary polyfills for IE10.

Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it looks like this is a bug affecting IE10 (and also Nativescript on Android), that won't be fixed.

Take a look:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/125